# WPF - KeyDown Event not working with Enter-Key

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress, keydown

I tried to implement a simple EventHandler in my WPF in which i tried to raise an Event every time the Enter-Key is pressed inside my GridControl.
It works with every other key but not Enter, which is unfortunately the only case where I want to do some stuff.
It also makes no difference whether the "KeyDown="OnKeyDown"" is in an surrounding Grid or the StackPanel inside the Grid or TextEdit's in the columns of the Grid inside the Stackpanel.
Either way, pressing enter doesnt throw an event as it should....

C# WPF DevExpress MVVM

[image: EventHandler in my xaml.cs]
When I set a breakpoint in the if, it breaks every time I enter something BUT NOT when pressing enter. In that case, the handler is not called which confuses me.

Comment: try e.Key == Key.Return

Comment: @Mate it doesnt matter. If i set a breakpoint at the if-clause its not getting hit when pressing enter but with every other key.

Comment: @Mate Key.Return and Key.Enter have identical value 6.

Comment: @ChrisGlant Use the PreviewKeyDown event.

Comment: @Clemens thanks that worked. But its interesting bc it didnt't work when I tried using the PreviewKeyDown event in my Grid-Columns but now I put it in the surrounding stackpanel and somehow it works